# Run a python script from a separate file on Laravel

Tags: python, laravel, selenium-webdriver, pytest, appium

I have a folder that consist a python Selenium Appium script and a Laravel folder, here is the folder path:

```
mobile-automation
   laravel
   app.py
```

What I'm trying to do is, I want to run the shell script `pytest -s app.py` from Laravel. So I already create the frontend using Laravel:

```
welcome.blade.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Run Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100" id="runScriptButton">All Feature</button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#runScriptButton').click(function () {
                // Execute an AJAX request to the /run-script route
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('runScript') }}", // Replace with your Laravel route
                    method: "GET",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert('Script executed successfully');
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert('Error: Script encountered an error');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

then there's the route

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\ScriptController;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/run-script', [ScriptController::class, 'runScript'])->name('runScript');
```

and the Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ScriptController extends Controller
{
    public function runScript()
    {
        try {
            // Your script execution code here
            $command = '/mobile-automation/app.py';
            exec($command, $output, $returnCode);
    
            if ($returnCode === 0) {
                return response('Script executed successfully', 200);
            } else {
                return response('Script encountered an error', 500);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Log the exception
            \Log::error('Error executing script: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return response('Internal Server Error', 500);
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the button, it gives an error `Error: Script encountered an error` and when I check the console:

[image]

Any solution on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check for file path , that you are executing , use shell_exec() function

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ScriptController extends Controller
{
    public function runScript()
    {
        try {
            // Your script execution code here
            $command = '/mobile-automation/app.py';
            $output=shell_exec($command);
   dd($output);
            if ($returnCode === 0) {
                return response('Script executed successfully', 200);
            } else {
                return response('Script encountered an error', 500);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Log the exception
            \Log::error('Error executing script: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return response('Internal Server Error', 500);
        }
    }
}
```